# Mock action invoked on controller initialization in AngularJS in test

Tags: javascript, testing, angularjs

I'm having angularjs controller that basically looks like below

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, service) {

  $scope.positions = service.loadPositions(); // this calls $http internally

  $scope.save = function() {
    ...
  };

  // other $scope functions here

});
```

Now every time I write test for any of the methods in $scope I need to stub `service.loadPositions()` like below:

```
  it(should 'save modified position', function($controller, service, $rootScope) {
    spyOn(service, 'loadPositions').andReturn(fakeData);

    var scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller('MyCtrl', {$scope: scope});

    // test stuff here
  })
```

Is there any way to avoid this first stubbing in every test? I mean If I already tested that this action is invoked on controller start, I don't really need stubbing this in every next test. This introduces a lot of repetition in each test.

**EDIT**

I stubmbled upon `ngInit` and I thought I could use it but it seems not to be recommended way do to such things, but I'm not sure why?

Answer (score 3):

Use a `beforeEach` inside your `describe` function:

```
describe('My test', function() {
    var $controller,
        $rootScope,
        serviceMock;

    beforeEach(function() {
        serviceMock = { loadPositions: function() {} };
        spyOn(serviceMock, 'loadPositions').andReturn(fakeData);

        inject(_$controller_, _$rootScope_) {
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_.$new();
            $controller = _$controller_('MyCtrl', 
                {$scope: $rootScope, service: serviceMock});
        };
    });

    it('should save modified position', function() {       
        // test stuff here
    });
});
```

Notice that I have moved the controller initialization to `beforeEach` as well so you don't have to do it again in every test.

Just in case you're wondering what the underscores in the `inject` arguments are for, they enable the test to declare a local `$controller` variable and a local `$rootScope` variable. Angular just ignores them when it's resolving the function dependencies.

**Update**: There was a little bug in the example code. Just fixed it.

Comment: Why do I need `$controller` in my tests? When controller gets instantiated with `$controller` call in `beforeEach` I  guess I should play with `$scope` only or am I wrong?

Comment: No, you're not. You can use it locally in `beforeEach` and then play with the scope in the tests. I'm used to keep a reference to the `$controller` service in my tests and I ended up doing the same here.

Answer (score 1):

You can move this into `beforeEach()` and use `$provide` to always return your fake service.

Not knowing all of your test code something like this should work.

```
var scope, controller;

beforeEach(module("app", function($provide){
    var mockedService = {
      loadPositions: function(){return fakeData;}//or use sinon
    };

    $provide.value('service', mockedService);
});   
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller;
}));

it(should 'save modified position', function() {


    controller('MyCtrl', {$scope: scope});

    // test stuff here
});
```